# Install python package if the pip will install too?

Tags: python, pip

I download the python3 [package](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-macosx10.6.pkg) , and install it, and I find the pip3 is installed too.

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ which python3
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ which pip3
....there I install the .dmg for python3 I download from the upper link.
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

So , I want to confirm if the pip3 package is include in the `.dmg` file, because when install the python3 the pip3 is installed too.

from the command lines you can see I only instal the python3 `dmg`, but the pip3 is installed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as expected.

Newer releases of Python 3 (3.4+?) come with pip pre-installed, as well as with the [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) module.